# Expectation value of $T_{\mu\nu}$ for uniform accelerating motion

Tags: reference-frames, renormalization, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Birrell and Davies in their book state that if $\langle \psi|T_{\mu\nu}|\psi\rangle = 0$ in one reference frame then it must be zero for all others whereas the particle content may vary for different observers (Section 3.3, pg 49).

In the [1976 paper](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1976.0045) by Davies and Fulling, it was shown that for uniformly accelerated moving boundaries in 2-D, using the retarded coordinates one can show that the expectation value of the stress-energy tensor vanishes (which was also proved in the book in chapter 6). But we know the same expectation value calculated in the Rindler coordinates yields $\langle T_{\mu\nu}\rangle = -\frac{1}{24\pi} {\rm I}_{2\times 2}$, where ${\rm I}_{2\times2}$ is the identity matrix in 2d which is nonzero (shown in the same paper and also in other books).

How do we reconcile these two statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends whether you regularize $T^{\mu\nu}$ to preserve its tensor property or not.  This the same as in 2d conformal field theory where the holomorphic normal-ordered $:T(z):$ transforms inhomogeneously by the addition of the Schwarzian,  but one can add a non-holomorphic $c$-number counter-term to $:T(z):$ so that their sum transforms as a tensor.  The first of  these objects tracks the particles that can be detected in the $z$ coordinate  frame, and the other includes the vacuum Casimir energy and is presumably the tensor that acts as a source term for gravity.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the conformal field theory, so your answer is a bit hard for me to understand. Am I correct in assuming that the regularization procedure adds some ambiguity to the transformation properties of the tensor which can be fixed by adding a pure c-number? What does this have to do with the particle concept? A bit of explanation for the specific example will be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry! These days more people know conformal stuff than general curved space. If you normal-order $T^{\mu\nu}$ in some co-ordinate frame then you will not have a tensor, but you are measuring the particles seen by a detector in that frame. This is because "positive frequency" is frame dependent. I think, however,  that one can  always add another term to make $T^{\mu\nu}$ transform as a tensor.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is $T_{\mu\nu} = :T_{\mu\nu}: + \langle T_{\mu\nu} \rangle$ where the second term is the Casimir energy. Now in the vacuum, the first term is zero, and in general, the second term also changes on what frame we choose (for example retarded or Rindler in the above case) being either zero or nonzero rendering the first statement in the OP false. Where am I wrong?

Comment: There is no frame-independent vacuum state "$|0\rangle$". If the quantum system is the Minkowski vaccum, then in the Rindler frame  there are particles present.

Comment: That is true. So then I guess what the first statement means is if we transform both the state and $|0\rangle$ and $T_{\mu\nu} $ to the new coordinate frame then $\langle \psi ' |T_{\mu\nu}'|\psi ' \rangle = 0$ where prime denotes values in the new reference frame given in the old reference frame we had $\langle \psi  |T_{\mu\nu}|\psi \rangle = 0$.